# How to disable Windows live Family Safety pops up?

Tags: windows-7

I have installed Windows Live Family and it's working great, I listed allowed site and it's blocking other perfectly.

One anoying thing.

In 'child' account every time I'm opening new site from allowed group it pops up window with information "Some content has been blocked", doesnt matter what site it is.

I want to disable this pop up, but there is no information in google about it.

[my original pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBbak.jpg)

[same in english from google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ec8ki.png)

Comment: Only here is a similar problem unsolved [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-security/windows-live-family-safety-login-pops-up/02b5882f-832c-4bab-99d3-289fc8758b51?db=5&auth=1)

Comment: it is probably loading pictures or advertisements from another site that you *didn't* allow.

Comment: @Aganju it may do whatever it want, i just dont want that information.